# Fix remove Rows in R (remove rows with specific negative value in one column)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, rows

I have datasets with 6 columns. First column is data. 4th column is "scPM25". The latter column has values 0, -1, -2 or NA.

I have to remove the rows with values -2. The rows with 0, -1 or NA should be keeped!

When I try various codes in R, I always get a complete NA dataset back. All codes I tried failed miserably.

some examples that failed:

all return complete NA set.

sds3 <- sds[sds$scPM25 >= -1.9, ]

sds5 <- filter(sds, scPM25 != -2)

sds6 <- filter(sds, scPM25 != "-2")

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example by pasting the output of `dput(head(sds))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is.na` and combine your condition with `|` (or) to subset like:

```
x  <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=c(0,-1,-2,NA))

x[is.na(x$b) | x$b != -2,]
#  a  b
#1 1  0
#2 2 -1
#4 4 NA

subset(x, is.na(b) | b != -2)
#1 1  0
#2 2 -1
#4 4 NA

#Or as @Cath suggested
subset(x, !b %in% (-2))
#  a  b
#1 1  0
#2 2 -1
#4 4 NA
```

Comment: using `%in%` instead of `==` permits to avoid the `NA` problem : `subset(x, !b %in% (-2))`

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```
data <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope', 'Freddie Mercury', 'Bob Dylan')
col2 <- c(21000, 23400, 26800, 27000, 39000)
col3 <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2007-3-14','2007-3-14'))
scPM25 <- c(-1, -2, NA, 0, -2)

sds <- data.frame(data, col2, col3, scPM25)

sds2 <- sds[is.na(sds$scPM25) | sds$scPM25 != -2, ]
```